# I want to display scoreboard on a sign in minecraft 1.13 or above

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm using this command to get a sign:

```
/give @p minecraft:oak_sign{BlockEntityTag:{
Text1:'{"text":"","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"setblock 43 17 13 minecraft:redstone_block"}}',
Text2:'{"text":"Buy Chicken","bold":true}',
Text3:'["0000000000",{"text":"\\u2588"},{"text":"\\u2588","color":"gray"}]'},display:{Name:'{"text":"Custom Sign"}'}
}
```

but I don't know how to make custom value with scoreboard in place of zeros on the third line of the sign.

Can someone help?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, at least in the base game.  This would be something possible with a proper mode, but scoreboard to text is almost as hard as NBT data text processing.

Comment: I found a solution:
On this page: https://minecraftjson.com we can create a command with scoreboard easily with "data merge block". This is an example:

/data merge block [x] [y] [z] {Text1:"{\"score\":{\"name\":\"PLAYER_OR_ENTITY\",\"objective\":\"SCOREBOARD_NAME\"},\"underlined\":true,\"color\":\"dark_red\"}"}

all we need to do then is to place a sign on correct [x] [y] [z].
The command need to be in "repeat" and "always active" command block.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: You should write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

On this page: https://minecraftjson.com, we can create a command with scoreboard easily with `/data merge block`. This is an example:

```
/data merge block [x] [y] [z] {Text1:"{\"score\":{\"name\":\"PLAYER_OR_ENTITY\",\"objective\":\"SCOREBOARD_NAME\"},\"underlined\":true,\"color\":\"dark_red\"}"}
```

All we need to do then is to place a sign on correct [x] [y] [z].
The command need to be in "repeat" and "always active" command block.